# Recycler view inside Coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout_survey_ques"
    tools:context=".survey.SurveyQuesActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/survey_ques_toolbar"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/survey_ques_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/survey_ques_toolbar"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/fab_submit"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_submit" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

when fab is clicked, the `snack bar` appears, for that, I have to use the coordinator layout to move the fab horizontally above the snack bar. But now the first few items of `recyclerview` is not visible. It only starts with item3. Can someone please help in solving this and what changes are to be made?

[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your layout, bug is probably in adapter for `RecyclerView`. show its code and some screen how it looks and, if possible, how should be

Comment: @snachmsm, i have added the picture of layout

Comment: Did You try Scrolling Down?

Comment: @SahilGoyal yes, in output half of the first item is missing

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use marginTop or RelativeLayout there is already a solution for this case in CoordinatiorLayout: `layout_behaviour`
Try using this structure in your main `XML` and add `scrolling layout behavior` for `RecyclerView`.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/survey_ques_recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior = "com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using `layout_below` for `RecyclerView`, but this attribute is intended to be used by `RelativeLayout` childrens, not `CoordinatorLayout`. so your items are there, but they are covered by `Toolbar`, as `RecyclerView` doesn't respect attr telling to align below `Toolbar`. Change your main container for `RelativeLayout` to get `layout_below` attribute working

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout_survey_ques"
    tools:context=".survey.SurveyQuesActivity">
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

note that `android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"` attribute set for `FloatingActionButton` will stop working, as this attr is inteneded to use with `LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout`, not `RelativeLayout`. you may want to use instead

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

edit: good point in comment. instead of above suggestions maybe try to add proper top margin for `RecyclerView` for placing it below `Toolbar`

```
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: when fab is clicked, snack bar appears, for that I have to use coordinator layout to move the fab horizontally above snack bar. This movement cannot be performed by relative layout, so I did with coordinator layout

Comment: true, check out my edit. lets try to add some margin for this `RecyclerView` for preventing being covered by `Toolbar`

Comment: consider upvoting/accepting my answer :) good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It seems your recyclerView is covered by included toolbar layout.  Can you try adding the top margin as the same as the height of your toolbar layout if hardcoded or if you used default Height `?attr/actionBarSize`

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/survey_ques_recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@id/survey_ques_toolbar"
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" /><!-- or height you gave in toolbar layout -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Put recyclerview inside Relative layout or any other layout like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
//Toolbar


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/survey_ques_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add recyclerview this code  `app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Recyclerview within the coordinator layout very easily, you can refer to the below code as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/myRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_6dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_layout_list" />
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_home"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/app_add_record_icon"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/textColorSecondary"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:tint="@null" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Cheers..!**